# UILabel in Prototype Cell does not take correct position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a `UITableView` contained in a UIViewController. This table view has only one prototype cell.

The cell contains a `UIImageView`, and two `UILabel`. The first label is set correctly (position and text). But the second is not positionned as expected.

I want this label to be centered horizontaly and verticaly in the cell's content view. But when I do `print(noFriendRequestLabel)`, the result is :

```
<UILabel: 0x7af81c00; frame = (-42 -21; 42 21); text = 'Aucune invitation'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7af82680>>
```

The label takes the correct text, but not the correct position. I'm using storyboard and auto-layout. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Below is the code of `cellForIndexPath()` :

```
// "Friends requests" section
         if indexPath.section == 0 {

            // If requests array is empty, show "No request" label
            if self.friendsRequestsArray.count == 0 {


                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendCustomCell


                cell.noFriendRequestLabel.hidden = false
                cell.noFriendRequestLabel.text   = NSLocalizedString("No request", comment: "")

                cell.friendAvatar.hidden = true
                cell.friendName.hidden   = true
                cell.friendButton.hidden = true

                print(cell.noFriendRequestLabel)
                return cell
            }

            // Else display friends requests
            else {

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendCustomCell


                cell.noFriendRequestLabel.hidden = true
                cell.friendAvatar.hidden         = false
                cell.friendName.hidden           = false
                cell.friendButton.hidden         = false


                cell.friendAvatar.image = self.friendsRequestsArray[indexPath.row].getAvatar()
                cell.friendName.text    = self.friendsRequestsArray[indexPath.row].toString()

                cell.user = self.friendsArray[indexPath.row]

                cell.user.delegate = UserEventsManager()

                return cell
            }
        }





        // "Your friends" section
        else {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendCustomCell

            cell.noFriendRequestLabel.hidden = true
            cell.friendAvatar.hidden         = false
            cell.friendName.hidden           = false
            cell.friendButton.hidden         = false

            cell.friendAvatar.image = self.friendsArray[indexPath.row].getAvatar()
            cell.friendName.text    = self.friendsArray[indexPath.row].toString()

            cell.user = self.friendsArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.user.delegate = UserEventsManager()

            return cell
        }
```

Any help would be grateful.

This is the constraint for the label :

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. Because on my second section, everything is displaying properly. The image and the label take place as expected, and the problematic label is correctly hidden, not nil.

Comment: Problem not in the code you posted but in the `NSLayoutConstraint` you defined in **IB**.

Comment: Screen shot + **IB** constraints?

Comment: Just edited my question.

Comment: That constraint in the screenshot is for one size class, rather than all size classes. Are you using the wrong size class?

Comment: I always used to use "This size class", everywhere in my storyboard. Actualy, I never ask myself about these two possibilities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what was happening.

In the `UIViewController` which contains the `UITableView`, I'm sending a request to a server, to fetch friends requests and current friends of the user.

So, when this request ends, I reload the table view's data. But, before, in `numberOfRowsInSection()`, I've set the number **before** the end of the request.

And the result was that I was reloading the data of the second section, and **not** of the first second (where I tried to show the label).

What worked for me is I've added a flag `loadData` in my custom `UITableView`, set to `false`. When the request in my controller ends, I set this flag to `true`. And in `numberOfRowsInSection()`, I return 0 if the flag is `false` or the number of rows for each section if it's `true`.